# Is there a way to get the current 'touch pattern' of an iPad/iPhone as a bitmap?

Tags: ios, touch

I want a lower level representation of the touch pattern. If someone lays their hand on the screen I want to see the hand shape. Is this possible in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As asked, the answer is no.  You might be able to do something by fetching all of the touch events in your beginTouches method, but even that is going to be a rough guess at best as the touch reporting is relatively limited when compared to taking a palm print (I don't have the technical details in front of me, but it's on the order of 10 simultaneous touches).

Comment: I certainly haven't found any APIs that get me deeper down closer to the hardware level. A little disappointing, but I think I can make my concept work regardless.